# Объединение построчно двух txt-файлов в один, через запятую. Python без использования pandas

Tags: python, массивы, объединение, txt

Есть два txt. в первом:

```
1
1
1
```

во втором:

```
2
2
2
```

мне нужно получить третий txt в формате:

```
1,2
1,2
1,2
```

Как можно это сделать без библиотеки pandas? у меня выходит только:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
```

Подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо

Comment: `with open('1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('2.txt', 'r') as f2, open('3.txt', 'w') as f3: for i, j in zip(f1.readlines(), f2.readlines()): f3.write(f"{i.strip()},{j.strip()}'\n'")` Размеры ведь одинаковые?

Comment: Да, размеры одинаковые

Comment: @EzikBro не нужно обрамлять '\n' кавычками... и можно без второго .strip(), просто f3.write(f'{i.strip()},{j}') добавьте как ответ?

Comment: Спасибо большое! все работает!

Answer (score 2):

Открываем файлы, читаем построчно, строки чистим, печатаем через запятую в третий файл:

```
with open('1.txt') as f1, open('2.txt') as f2, open('3.txt', 'w') as f3:
    for p in zip(f1, f2):
        print(*map(lambda s: s.strip(), p), sep=',', file=f3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f1 = open('1.txt')
f2 = open("2.txt")
f3 = open("3.txt", "w")

n1 = f1.read().splitlines()
n2 = f2.read().splitlines()

for i in range(len(n1)):
    f3.writelines(n1[i] + "," + n2[i]+ "\n")


f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
```